# Compute $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{(z-4)(z-1)} dz$ where $\gamma$ is centered at $4$ with radius $1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

So I know inside of $\gamma$ the only singularity is at $z=4$ so by Cauchy's Integral formula I define $f(z):=\frac{1}{z-1}$ Then I can compute

$$\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-4}dz=2 \pi i f(4)=\frac{2 \pi i }{3}$$

Where the winding number about $4$ is just $1$. Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Looks good.   You can also do this with the residue theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-4)}\frac{1}{(z-1)}$.
You have a simple zero at $z=4$. Then by the residu theorem
$$\int_\gamma\frac{1}{(z-4)}\frac{1}{(z-1)}dz=Res(f,4)=2\pi i\lim_{z\rightarrow 4}(z-4)\frac{1}{(z-4)}\frac{1}{(z-1)}=\frac{2\pi i}{3}$$.